# Time series analysis every 15 min

Tags: r, time-series, rstudio, analysis

I'm trying to forecast a series in R quantities are measured every 15 minutes, from 7/10/2010 1:15 to 8/26/2010 23:45.  can I write this by ts(power,frequency =96) given that the peek is at 19:30 everyday ??

Comment: Assuming power is a numeric vector then you can define a ts object that way.

Comment: if your cycle length is one day, then you can use frequency = 96. But if you have a longer cycle which shows repetitive patterns (like possibly week or month or year) that you want to include in your model, than reducing the cycle to one day wont serve (from what I understand). Be aware, that you will have to fill and impute missing data points when using the frequency (in your case if one cylce has less or more than 96 observations all following cycles will be offset and result in bad predictions)

Comment: how can i make sure of my cycle length in r other than acf ??

Comment: @sam can you explain your context? (in general you would need at least two closed cycles for something like ARIMA). One possible way to avoid the frequency question is to use minute, hour, day, weekday, week, month  and year (possibly more feature engineering like identification "morning/evening/night", etc. might help) as individual explanatory variables and feed an algorithm like neural net with it. This would let the algorithm figure out what the pattern.

Comment: @sam you can also experiment with different cycle length and work out the best option for your case from the prediction results (be sure to evalute the prediction on something like a rolling time window and not only train one model an evaluate it on the latest data recorded)

Comment: I'm trying to find the best model for prediction , first i want to use Holt winters but it is giving me error saying frequency too high when i try 96 or even 52 ,

Comment: @DPH i need to forecast the power consumption for the next day aka 96 15 min

Comment: I suppose the hold winters implementation is made for monthly pattern (12) or lower ... probably everything arround ARIMA is for frquency 12 or lower (I would have to read into it though to be sure). I would use a neural net approach for your case like I mentioned before when focussing on 15min pattern (https://kourentzes.com/forecasting/2017/02/10/forecasting-time-series-with-neural-networks-in-r/). I also remember reading something about hyndman wokring on a tidyverse implemenations for analysing and forecasting that might cover data with higher frequency: https://robjhyndman.com/software/

Comment: @sam depending on the origin of your observed data it might be interessing to include sunlight, tempreature and/or rain as explanatory variables. For example: in locations like australia the use of airconditions can represent a relevant part of energy consumption on hot and dry days (the hotter the higher the energy consumptions for airconditions but if the day is rainy possible the consumption will be way lower than normally expected for the period of the year)

Comment: @sam forgot to say: when setting up you data with explanatory variables you could use also H2Os automl() function -> this applies a few algorithms including decisino trees and does some data prep by itseld... I have had good results with h2o in the past when working with 15min intervals...

Comment: so frequency has to be 96 at the end ? no other way around it ? btw thank u very much

Comment: @sam you only need frequency if you want to work and analyse your data as a timeseries object. If you opt for representing your data & time with multiple individual explanatory variables (minute, hour, etc) you can use H2Os automl() or other algorithms that do not take ts objects as input and let them figure out the pattern. h2o.automl() is pretty good option to start when not using timeseries as ts object (at least for me) as it also does ensamble models automatically on top, which can be very helpfull for your case (have a look here how it can be done: https://rpubs.com/phamdinhkhanh/390053)